# Carousel should move only one image using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm able to move images in the Carousel using Angular JS. But the issue is, its moving threeimages at one time, I just want one image to move so that one new image can be inserted. Page should have three images, but only one image should be moved and the next image should be inserted. Please find the code

```
$scope.displayMode = "tablet";
//##################################################
if ($scope.displayMode == "mobile") {many = 1;}
else if ($scope.displayMode == "tablet") {many = 2;} 
else {many = 3;}

for (i = 0; i < $scope.slides.length; i += many) {
  second = {
    image1: $scope.slides[i]
  };
  if (many == 1) {}
  if ($scope.slides[i + 1] && (many == 2 || many == 3)) {
    second.image2 = $scope.slides[i + 1];

  }
  if ($scope.slides[i + (many - 1)] && many == 3) {
    second.image3 = $scope.slides[i + 2];
  }
  first.push(second);
}
console.log(first);
```

Plunker code is http://plnkr.co/edit/umswXrj8AgpK7T2dP9Pk?p=preview

Comment: if you want one image per slide then you should change **i+=many**  to `for (i = 0; i < $scope.slides.length; i++)`

Comment: No @Manu Antony.. You didn't get my point. Each page should show three images, but on going to next page, only one image should be shifted